# Como capturar variable SESSION PHP con JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery

Este variable esta en una vista .php

```
<?php $actualizar=$_SESSION["actualizar"]; ?>
```

Esta esta en un archivo .js se esta trabajando bajo el model mvc

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
// the "href" attribute of the modal trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
            $('#modal2').modal({
        dismissible: false, // Modal can be dismissed by clicking outside of the modal
        inDuration: 3000, // Transition in duration
        outDuration: 200, // Transition out duration
        startingTop: '4%', // Starting top style attribute
        endingTop: '10%', // Ending top style attribute
      });

            $('#modal2').modal('open');
    });
```

alguna idea de como capturar esa variable session en jquery ?

Comment: Si lo pones en un input hidden?

Comment: si se que lo lograria. pero me pregunto si existe otro tipo de metodo

Comment: Que framework estas utilizando para manejar tu mvc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Tienes la posibilidad de guardarlo en una cookie en vez de una sesión? Las sesiones no se pueden obtener directamente con JS pero las cookies sí.

Teniendo:

```
<?php
    $actualizar = 'cookie de ejemplo'; // Valor de la cookie
    setcookie('actualizar', $actualizar, time() + 3600); // Crear cookie de 1h (3600s)
?>
```

En JavaScript puedes obtener `$_COOKIE['actualizar']` así:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    let value = '; ' + document.cookie;
    let parts = value.split('; ' + name + '=');

    if (parts.length == 2) {
        return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
    }
}

let cookie_actualizar = getCookie('actualizar');
console.log(cookie_actualizar); // Imprime en consola: "cookie de ejemplo"
```